# Why won't this code work to generate a tilemap?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to create a tilemap for my game with some mario sprites. For some reason, no images are loading and I've tried everything I can think of.

I have tried the following code to generate my map with a 2d array:

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

var testMap = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];

        var testBlock = new Image();
        testBlock.src = "./img/52571.png"

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

function drawMap () {
    for (var i = 0; i < testMap.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < testMap[i].length; j++) {
        if (testMap[i][j] == 1) {
            ctx.drawImage(testBlock, 0, 0, 16, 16, posX, posY, 16, 16);
        }
        posX += 16;
    }
    posX = 0;
    posY += 16;
    };
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "GameCanvas" width = "800" height = "480"></canvas>
    <script src ='game_main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [tileset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6JFX.png).

Can anyone provide some insight on why this is not working?

Comment: what is `ctx` ?

Comment: ctx is the canvas get context for 2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your image is loaded before you draw with it.

You can do that by calling `drawMap` in `testBlock.onload`.

Here's a working demo (just click `Run code snippet`):

```js
var testMap = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

var testBlock = new Image();
testBlock.onload = drawMap;
testBlock.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6JFX.png"

function drawMap() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  
  var posX = 0;
  var posY = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < testMap.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < testMap[i].length; j++) {
      if (testMap[i][j] == 1) {
        ctx.drawImage(testBlock, 0, 0, 16, 16, posX, posY, 16, 16);
      }
      posX += 16;
    }
    posX = 0;
    posY += 16;
  };
}
```

```html
<body>

  <canvas id="GameCanvas" width="160" height="96" style="border:1px solid #000000;" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you defined `drawMap` function but it is not called. Call the drawMap function on `onload` of image.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var testMap = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];

const testBlock = new Image();
testBlock.src = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg"
testBlock.onload = drawMap;

let posX = 0;
let posY = 0;

function drawMap () {
    for (let i = 0; i < testMap.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < testMap[i].length; j++) {
        if (testMap[i][j] == 1) {
            ctx.drawImage(testBlock, 0, 0, 16, 16, posX, posY, 16, 16);
        }
        posX += 16;
    }
    posX = 0;
    posY += 16;
    };
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "GameCanvas" width = "800" height = "480"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! It was very helpful, and now I can move on.

Comment: @Twickz - If the solution solves your problem, mark it as accepted so as to indicate that problem has been resolved.